# Reading fixed width data: positioning row using a marker

Tags: r, tidyverse, fixed-width, readr

I (should) have a fixed width data like this,

```
134265311
125255388
199265335
```

I can read the data like this,

```
first_ex <- readr::read_fwf("~/example_1.txt", fwf_widths(c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)))
first_ex
> first_ex
# A tibble: 3 x 6
     X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    34     2    65     3    11
2     1    25     2    55     3    88
3     1    99     2    65     3    35
```

The `X1, X3, X5`, i.e. the first digits (1, 2 and 3) of the original data are the markers for the next column.

Now, I have data like this,

```
265311
125388
335
```

In the first row the datapoint with marker 1, second row datapoint with marker 2 and third row datapoint with market 1 and 2 are missing. I want to find a way to convert the data like the following one,

```
> first_ex1
# A tibble: 3 x 6
     X1 X2       X3 X4       X5    X6
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 00        2 65        3    11
2     1 25        2 00        3    88
3     1 00        2 00        3    35
```

Any help, suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**Addition**

I am trying to implement @ suggestion in the following dataset, where `l.group <- 16` and `max.index <- 99`. The index starts from 10 (2 digits instead of 1).

```
values <- c("1300000190000148200000005000003099000002400001789800000050000030", 
          "1300000190000198290000003000001299000002200002109800000030000012",
          "130000064000011499000006400001149800000000000000",
          "1300000180000129330000003000002199000002100001509800000030000021", 
          "130000025000018099000002500001809800000000000000", 
          "13000001900000633100000020000002480000001000001699000002200000819800000030000018")
```

I am not having the output I want. E.g. if the column marker is 13, then the corresponding column number should be V25 and V26. But I see different in the output;

[image]

How to fit the code into my data perfectly?

Comment: It is difficult to differentiate between the marker and other digits.  What if there are digits there are markers that are not in the correcxt position.

Comment: @akrun In fact it is easy. The first character of every three characters should always be the identifier, e.g. in the first row, the identifier are 2 and 3, in the second it is 1 and 3 and the in the last it is 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
library(stringi)
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

values <- c(265311,
            125388,
            335)

# length of each group, for splitting up
l.group <- 3
# what is the maximum we go up to e.g. 1,2,3 at the moment
max.index <- 3
# NEW: number of digits, has to be same for all
digits <- 1

# make a template
grid <- as.data.table(matrix(sapply(1:max.index, function(x){c(x,0)}), nrow=1))

# split them up from one string
values.split <- trimws(gsub(sprintf("(.{%s})", l.group), "\\1 ", values)) %>%
  stringi::stri_split_regex(., "\\s")

# loop through, append to grid and combine
output <- lapply(values.split, function(x){
  # NEW: made it depend on the digits of index
  index <- as.integer(as.numeric(stringi::stri_sub(x, 1, digits))*2)  
  values <- as.numeric(stringi::stri_sub(x, (digits+1), nchar(x)))
  out <- copy(grid)
  for(i in seq_along(index)) set(out, j=index[i], value=values[i])
  out
}) %>% rbindlist(.)
output[]
```

with the new e.g. try with `digits <- 2`

Comment: Thanks a lot. The scenario I have described in the question worked perfectly under what you have described. However, I am adding a complex case in the original problem. Any suggestion how to fix that?

Comment: It's difficult. How would you know what the split is, now that the order of the strings has no direction? e.g. splitting the first string in your new `values` gives indexes of `13, 2, 99, 98` (I'm guessing) e.g. if you give me,`13012101` this could split to `(1, 301, 2, 101)` or `(13, 01, 21, 01)` etc. There has to be something structured in the input data or else any script written will solve some problems but not all. As soon as you have both single and double digits in the same string it becomes much harder to solve. Are there any key patterns to help distinguish between these?

Comment: If it will always be single digits, or always 2 digits etc. then it becomes easy again, you would just need to change the part that splits `index` and `value`. I have edited to allow for a `digits` parameter that will work if all cases have the same number